How OPCODES fees were defined?
When a function from a contract is executed the total cost, in weis, is calculated based on the OPCODES executed.
For example, this question shows how to calculate the gas cost for keccak, that is 30 gas + extra gas for input.
How was defined the fee of each OPCODE? Is the fee correlated with some measure of computational processing like MIPS or cycles?

An excellent question. I really don't know the exact answer, but might provide a bit more information.
As I see it, there are at least the following aspects that should/might have influenced the numbers:

How much computation the operation requires
How much storage
How much network bandwidth
Does it cause other side effects or unwanted behavior, such as DDoS attack vectors

But that's not the full story.
Some operations are expensive to perform (in computational sense), but are relatively cheap on-chain. These have their own precompiled contracts. There are not many such operations, but for various reasons eth core devs have decided that those operations should be cheaper than they would be with "regular" calculations.
In the end, as I said, I don't know the real story behind the calculations. Partially just speculating here.
